# How can I create a sequential id for each group based on 3-day interval?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, time-series

I have a dataframe df looks like this:

| service | phone_number | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAABBB | AAAAAAAA | 12/04/2023 |
| AAABBB | AAAAAAAA | 12/04/2023 |
| AAABBB | AAAAAAAA | 13/04/2023 |
| AAABBB | AAAAAAAA | 15/04/2023 |
| CCCDDD | AAAAAAAA | 15/04/2023 |
| CCCDDD | AAAAAAAA | 15/04/2023 |
| CCCDDD | AAAAAAAA | 17/04/2023 |
| CCCDDD | AAAAAAAA | 18/04/2023 |
| CCCDDD | AAAAAAAA | 18/04/2023 |
| CCCDDD | AAAAAAAA | 19/04/2023 |
| AAABBB | BBBBBB | 29/05/2023 |
| AAABBB | BBBBBB | 03/06/2023 |
| AAABBB | BBBBBB | 13/06/2023 |
| AAABBB | BBBBBB | 19/06/2023 |
| CCCDDD | BBBBBB | 16/02/2023 |
| CCCDDD | BBBBBB | 17/02/2023 |
| CCCDDD | BBBBBB | 18/02/2023 |
| CCCDDD | BBBBBB | 20/02/2023 |

I need to create for each df group (service and phone number) a sequential id (seq) within the 3-day time windows:

Eventually, the data should look like this:

| service | phone_number | date | seq | method |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAABBB | AAAAAAAA | 12/04/2023 | 1 | Start of the time window |
| AAABBB | AAAAAAAA | 12/04/2023 | 1 | Within the time window |
| AAABBB | AAAAAAAA | 13/04/2023 | 1 | Within the time window |
| AAABBB | AAAAAAAA | 15/04/2023 | 2 | Time window shifts to the next row |
| CCCDDD | AAAAAAAA | 15/04/2023 | 1 | Start of a new combination's time window |
| CCCDDD | AAAAAAAA | 15/04/2023 | 1 | Within the time window |
| CCCDDD | AAAAAAAA | 17/04/2023 | 1 | Within the time window |
| CCCDDD | AAAAAAAA | 18/04/2023 | 2 | Time window shifts to the next row |
| CCCDDD | AAAAAAAA | 18/04/2023 | 2 | Within the time window |
| CCCDDD | AAAAAAAA | 19/04/2023 | 2 | Time window shifts to the next row |
| AAABBB | BBBBBB | 29/05/2023 | 1 | Start of a new combination's time window |
| AAABBB | BBBBBB | 03/06/2023 | 2 | Time window shifts to the next row |
| AAABBB | BBBBBB | 13/06/2023 | 3 | Time window shifts to the next row |
| AAABBB | BBBBBB | 19/06/2023 | 4 | Time window shifts to the next row |
| CCCDDD | BBBBBB | 16/02/2023 | 1 | Start of a new combination's time window |
| CCCDDD | BBBBBB | 17/02/2023 | 1 | Within the time window |
| CCCDDD | BBBBBB | 18/02/2023 | 1 | Within the time window |
| CCCDDD | BBBBBB | 20/02/2023 | 2 | Time window shifts to the next row |

I am working in Databricks, so both pandas and pyspark are fine

Any help or comments are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

I tried various approaches but none of them gave me the desired results :(

The obtained output with the proposed code (@mozway) on my dataset:

for example, for the dates 16/02/2023, 17/02/2023 and18/02/2023, I get two separate ranks, but the 3-days time window is the same

| Index | Service | Phone Number | Date | Step 1: Time Difference | Step 2: Divided Time | Step 3: Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 04/01/2023 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 04/01/2023 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 10/01/2023 | 6 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 11/01/2023 | 7 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 11/01/2023 | 7 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 11/01/2023 | 7 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 11/01/2023 | 7 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 11/01/2023 | 7 | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 11/01/2023 | 7 | 2 | 2 |
| 9 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 12/01/2023 | 8 | 3 | 2 |
| 10 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 12/01/2023 | 8 | 3 | 2 |
| 11 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 12/01/2023 | 8 | 3 | 2 |
| 12 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 14/01/2023 | 10 | 3 | 3 |
| 13 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 19/01/2023 | 15 | 5 | 4 |
| 14 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 19/01/2023 | 15 | 5 | 4 |
| 15 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 19/01/2023 | 15 | 5 | 4 |
| 16 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 19/01/2023 | 15 | 5 | 4 |
| 17 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 19/01/2023 | 15 | 5 | 4 |
| 18 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 19/01/2023 | 15 | 5 | 4 |
| 19 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 25/01/2023 | 21 | 7 | 5 |
| 20 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 30/01/2023 | 26 | 9 | 6 |
| 21 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 30/01/2023 | 26 | 9 | 6 |
| 22 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 16/02/2023 | 43 | 14 | 7 |
| 23 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 16/02/2023 | 43 | 14 | 7 |
| 24 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 17/02/2023 | 44 | 15 | 7 |
| 25 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 17/02/2023 | 44 | 15 | 7 |
| 26 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 17/02/2023 | 44 | 15 | 7 |
| 27 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 17/02/2023 | 44 | 15 | 7 |
| 28 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 17/02/2023 | 44 | 15 | 7 |
| 29 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 17/02/2023 | 44 | 15 | 7 |
| 30 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 18/02/2023 | 45 | 15 | 8 |
| 31 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 18/02/2023 | 45 | 15 | 8 |
| 32 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 18/02/2023 | 45 | 15 | 8 |
| 33 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 18/02/2023 | 45 | 15 | 8 |
| 34 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 18/02/2023 | 45 | 15 | 8 |
| 35 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 18/02/2023 | 45 | 15 | 8 |
| 36 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 18/02/2023 | 45 | 15 | 8 |
| 37 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 18/02/2023 | 45 | 15 | 8 |
| 38 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 18/02/2023 | 45 | 15 | 8 |
| 39 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 18/02/2023 | 45 | 15 | 8 |
| 40 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 18/02/2023 | 45 | 15 | 8 |
| 41 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 18/02/2023 | 45 | 15 | 8 |
| 42 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 20/02/2023 | 47 | 16 | 9 |
| 43 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 20/02/2023 | 47 | 16 | 9 |
| 44 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 20/02/2023 | 47 | 16 | 9 |
| 45 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 20/02/2023 | 47 | 16 | 9 |
| 46 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 20/02/2023 | 47 | 16 | 9 |
| 47 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 20/02/2023 | 47 | 16 | 9 |
| 48 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 20/02/2023 | 47 | 16 | 9 |
| 49 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 20/02/2023 | 47 | 16 | 9 |
| 50 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 20/02/2023 | 47 | 16 | 9 |
| 51 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 20/02/2023 | 47 | 16 | 9 |
| 52 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 21/02/2023 | 48 | 16 | 9 |
| 53 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 21/02/2023 | 48 | 16 | 9 |
| 54 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 21/02/2023 | 48 | 16 | 9 |
| 55 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 21/02/2023 | 48 | 16 | 9 |
| 56 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 21/02/2023 | 48 | 16 | 9 |
| 57 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 22/02/2023 | 49 | 16 | 10 |
| 58 | AAABBB | AAAAAAAAA | 22/02/2023 | 49 | 16 | 10 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### counting 3 days windows relative to the start

You can use a custom function and [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html).

In the function, compute the difference to the min date per group, then perform a [`floordiv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.floordiv.html) on 3 days, finally [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) the values with a dense method:

```
def f(s, freq='3D'):
    return (s.sub(s.min()).floordiv(pd.Timedelta(freq))
             .rank(method='dense').astype(int)
           )

df['seq'] = df.groupby(['service', 'phone_number'])['date'].transform(f)
```

Output:

```
   service phone_number       date  seq
0   AAABBB     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-12    1
1   AAABBB     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-12    1
2   AAABBB     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-13    1
3   AAABBB     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-15    2
4   CCCDDD     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-15    1
5   CCCDDD     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-15    1
6   CCCDDD     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-17    1
7   CCCDDD     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-18    2
8   CCCDDD     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-18    2
9   CCCDDD     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-19    2
10  AAABBB       BBBBBB 2023-05-29    1
11  AAABBB       BBBBBB 2023-06-03    2
12  AAABBB       BBBBBB 2023-06-13    3
13  AAABBB       BBBBBB 2023-06-19    4
14  CCCDDD       BBBBBB 2023-02-16    1
15  CCCDDD       BBBBBB 2023-02-17    1
16  CCCDDD       BBBBBB 2023-02-18    1
17  CCCDDD       BBBBBB 2023-02-20    2
```

If you want to change the frequency:

```
df['seq'] = (df.groupby(['service', 'phone_number'])['date']
               .transform(f, freq='7D') # pass the parameter here
             )

   service phone_number       date  seq
0   AAABBB     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-12    1
1   AAABBB     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-12    1
2   AAABBB     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-13    1
3   AAABBB     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-15    1
4   CCCDDD     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-15    1
5   CCCDDD     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-15    1
6   CCCDDD     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-17    1
7   CCCDDD     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-18    1
8   CCCDDD     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-18    1
9   CCCDDD     AAAAAAAA 2023-04-19    1
10  AAABBB       BBBBBB 2023-05-29    1
11  AAABBB       BBBBBB 2023-06-03    1
12  AAABBB       BBBBBB 2023-06-13    2
13  AAABBB       BBBBBB 2023-06-19    3
14  CCCDDD       BBBBBB 2023-02-16    1
15  CCCDDD       BBBBBB 2023-02-17    1
16  CCCDDD       BBBBBB 2023-02-18    1
17  CCCDDD       BBBBBB 2023-02-20    1
```

##### counting 3 days windows relative the the first date of each window (i.e. restarting the reference)

Here you cannot use vectorial methods, you need a loop:

```
def f(s, freq='3D'):
    out = []
    last_ref = pd.Timestamp(0)
    n = 0
    for day in s:
        if day > last_ref + pd.Timedelta(freq):
            n += 1
            last_ref = day
        out.append(n)
    return out

df['seq'] = df.groupby(['Service', 'Phone Number'])['date'].transform(f)
```

Output:

```
    Index Service Phone Number       Date  seq
0       0  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-04    1
1       1  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-04    1
2       2  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-10    2
3       3  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-11    2
4       4  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-11    2
5       5  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-11    2
6       6  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-11    2
7       7  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-11    2
8       8  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-11    2
9       9  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-12    2
10     10  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-12    2
11     11  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-12    2
12     12  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-14    3
13     13  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-19    4
14     14  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-19    4
15     15  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-19    4
16     16  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-19    4
17     17  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-19    4
18     18  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-19    4
19     19  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-25    5
20     20  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-30    6
21     21  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-01-30    6
22     22  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-16    7
23     23  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-16    7
24     24  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-17    7
25     25  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-17    7
26     26  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-17    7
27     27  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-17    7
28     28  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-17    7
29     29  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-17    7
30     30  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-18    7
31     31  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-18    7
32     32  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-18    7
33     33  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-18    7
34     34  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-18    7
35     35  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-18    7
36     36  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-18    7
37     37  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-18    7
38     38  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-18    7
39     39  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-18    7
40     40  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-18    7
41     41  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-18    7
42     42  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-20    8
43     43  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-20    8
44     44  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-20    8
45     45  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-20    8
46     46  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-20    8
47     47  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-20    8
48     48  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-20    8
49     49  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-20    8
50     50  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-20    8
51     51  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-20    8
52     52  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-21    8
53     53  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-21    8
54     54  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-21    8
55     55  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-21    8
56     56  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-21    8
57     57  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-22    8
58     58  AAABBB    AAAAAAAAA 2023-02-22    8
```

Comment: thank you @mozway for looking into it :). However, this works for the small data that I pasted here but if I apply this on a larger dataset with serval repeated dates the result is not correct.

Comment: @deps I see, you want to restart the reference whenever a new group is formed. Then there is unfortunately no straightforward vectorial method for this, you need to use a loop. See update: