# How to convert Python Pandas function to Python PySpark without using UDF function

Tags: python, pandas, loops, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have this function explained in details in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76538171/how-can-i-create-a-sequential-id-for-each-group-based-on-3-day-interval)

```
df = df.toPandas()

def f(s, freq='3D'):
    out = []
    last_ref = pd.Timestamp(0)
    n = 0
    for day in s:
        if day > last_ref + pd.Timedelta(freq):
            n += 1
            last_ref = day
        out.append(n)
    return out

df['seq'] = df.groupby(['Service', 'Phone Number'])['date'].transform(f)
```

It worked perfectly, however, my cluster in Unity Catalog Databricks (Runtime 13.1) has changed some specifications and I can not longer use this function (moreover UDF functions are not supported).

How do I transform this function in pyspark code without using a UDF function?

Any help or comments are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Here the updated @samkart output, with other sample data

the seq_pandas column is the output I would like to get

| date | service | phone_number | seq_pyspark | seq_pandas | logic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/11/2021 | AAAA | 555555 | 1 | 1 | first date of the service phone number |
| 09/12/2021 | BBBB | 555555 | 1 | 1 | first date of the service phone number |
| 11/12/2021 | BBBB | 555555 | 2 | 1 | falls within the 3-day interval, same seq as the previous row |
| 14/01/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 3 | 2 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 31/01/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 4 | 3 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 14/02/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 5 | 4 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 16/02/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 6 | 4 | falls within the 3-day interval, same seq as the previous row |
| 24/03/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 7 | 5 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 12/04/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 8 | 6 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 13/04/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 9 | 6 | falls within the 3-day interval, same seq as the previous row |
| 13/04/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 9 | 6 | falls within the 3-day interval, same seq as the previous row |
| 04/05/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 10 | 7 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 04/05/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 10 | 7 | falls within the 3-day interval, same seq as the previous row |
| 21/05/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 11 | 8 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 23/05/2022 | AAAA | 555555 | 2 | 1 | first date of the service phone number |

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spark's window functions like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lag, sum as spark_sum, when

window_spec = Window.partitionBy('Service', 'Phone Number').orderBy('date')

df = df.withColumn('last_ref', lag(col('date')).over(window_spec))
df = df.withColumn('n', when(col('date') > (col('last_ref') + expr("INTERVAL 3 DAYS")), 1).otherwise(0))
df = df.withColumn('seq', spark_sum('n').over(window_spec))
df = df.drop('last_ref', 'n')
```

Comment: Hi @Omid Roshani, Really thanks for the fast reply! However the obtained output with the proposted pyspark code is different. See the post