# How to create a 3-day rolling sequential id for each group using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I've been struggling with this issue for some time now. ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76674032/how-to-convert-python-pandas-function-to-python-pyspark-without-using-udf-functi)).

I would like to create a 3-day sequential id for each group (phone_number and service).
The id should start from the first date of the group and restart at the end of the 3-day interval.

I work in Databricks Unity Catalog with a runtime cluster of 13.1 (no udf supported)

Here what I would like to achieve

| date | service | phone_number | desired_seq | logic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/11/2021 | AAAA | 555555 | 1 | first date of the service phone number |
| 09/12/2021 | BBBB | 555555 | 1 | first date of the service phone number |
| 11/12/2021 | BBBB | 555555 | 1 | falls within the 3-day interval, same seq as the previous row |
| 14/01/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 2 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 31/01/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 3 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 14/02/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 4 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 16/02/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 4 | falls within the 3-day interval, same seq as the previous row |
| 24/03/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 5 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 12/04/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 6 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 13/04/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 6 | falls within the 3-day interval, same seq as the previous row |
| 13/04/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 6 | falls within the 3-day interval, same seq as the previous row |
| 04/05/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 7 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 04/05/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 7 | falls within the 3-day interval, same seq as the previous row |
| 21/05/2022 | BBBB | 555555 | 8 | doesn't fall within the 3-day interval, restarts seq |
| 23/05/2022 | AAAA | 555555 | 2 | falls within the 3-day interval, same seq as the previous row |

Any help or comments are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Both of them do not work for my goal:

**Example df:**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# example df
data = [
    ("06/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("06/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("06/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("07/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("09/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("09/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("12/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("12/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("12/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("13/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("14/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("16/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("16/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("16/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("16/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("16/06/2023", "33333", "AAAA"),
    ("07/06/2023", "33333", "BBBB"),
    ("07/06/2023", "33333", "BBBB"),
    ("09/06/2023", "33333", "BBBB"),
    ("09/06/2023", "33333", "BBBB"),
    ("10/06/2023", "33333", "BBBB"),
    ("12/06/2023", "33333", "BBBB"),
    ("12/06/2023", "33333", "BBBB"),
    ("16/06/2023", "33333", "BBBB")
]

# schema
schema = ["date", "phone_number", "service"]
```

1-@Jonathan Lam

**method:**

```
# 3days seq
df.withColumn(
    'prev_date', func.lag('date', 1).over(Window.partitionBy('service', 'phone_number').orderBy('date'))
).withColumn(
    'date_seq', func.sum(func.when(
        func.datediff(func.to_date(func.col('date'), 'dd/MM/yyyy'), func.to_date(func.col('prev_date'), 'dd/MM/yyyy'))<=3,
        func.lit(0)
    ).otherwise(
        func.lit(1)
    )).over(Window.partitionBy('service', 'phone_number').orderBy('date'))
).orderBy(
    ['service', 'phone_number', 'date']
).show(
    100, False
)
```

**output:**

```
+----------+------------+-------+----------+--------+
|date      |phone_number|service|prev_date |date_seq|
+----------+------------+-------+----------+--------+
|06/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |null      |1       |
|06/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |06/06/2023|1       |
|06/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |06/06/2023|1       |
|07/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |06/06/2023|1       |
|09/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |07/06/2023|1       |
|09/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |09/06/2023|1       |
|12/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |09/06/2023|2       |
|12/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |12/06/2023|2       |
|12/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |12/06/2023|2       |
|13/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |12/06/2023|2       |
|14/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |13/06/2023|2       |
|16/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |14/06/2023|2       |
|16/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |16/06/2023|2       |
|16/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |16/06/2023|2       |
|16/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |16/06/2023|2       |
|16/06/2023|33333       |AAAA   |16/06/2023|2       |
|07/06/2023|33333       |BBBB   |null      |1       |
|07/06/2023|33333       |BBBB   |07/06/2023|1       |
|09/06/2023|33333       |BBBB   |07/06/2023|1       |
|09/06/2023|33333       |BBBB   |09/06/2023|1       |
|10/06/2023|33333       |BBBB   |09/06/2023|1       |
|12/06/2023|33333       |BBBB   |10/06/2023|1       |
|12/06/2023|33333       |BBBB   |12/06/2023|1       |
|16/06/2023|33333       |BBBB   |12/06/2023|2       |
+----------+------------+-------+----------+--------+
```

2-@Lamanus

**method:**

```
# Creazione del DataFrame
df = df.withColumn('date', f.to_timestamp('date', 'd/M/y'))

w = Window.partitionBy('service', "phone_number").orderBy('date')

df.withColumn('lag', f.lag('date').over(w)) \
  .withColumn('jump', f.coalesce(f.datediff('date', 'lag') > 3, f.lit(True))) \
  .withColumn('desired_seq', f.sum(f.col('jump').cast('int')).over(w)).drop('lag', 'jump').show()
```

**output:**

```
+-------------------+------------+-------+-----------+
|               date|phone_number|service|desired_seq|
+-------------------+------------+-------+-----------+
|2023-06-06 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-06 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-06 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-07 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-09 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-09 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-12 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-12 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-12 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-13 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-14 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-16 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-16 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-16 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-16 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-16 00:00:00|       33333|   AAAA|          1|
|2023-06-07 00:00:00|       33333|   BBBB|          1|
|2023-06-07 00:00:00|       33333|   BBBB|          1|
|2023-06-09 00:00:00|       33333|   BBBB|          1|
|2023-06-09 00:00:00|       33333|   BBBB|          1|
+-------------------+------------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Why the value of `desired_seq` of last row is not `2`? The first `AAAA` - `555555` has already appeared at the first row right?

Comment: yes sorry it's 2! it was a typing error

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('01/01/2023', 'AAAA', 555555),
        ('02/01/2023', 'AAAA', 555555),
        ('03/01/2023', 'AAAA', 555555),
        ('10/01/2023', 'AAAA', 555555)
    ],
    schema=['date', 'service', 'phone_number']
)

df.printSchema()
df.show(10, False)
root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- service: string (nullable = true)
 |-- phone_number: long (nullable = true)

+----------+-------+------------+
|date      |service|phone_number|
+----------+-------+------------+
|01/01/2023|AAAA   |555555      |
|02/01/2023|AAAA   |555555      |
|03/01/2023|AAAA   |555555      |
|10/01/2023|AAAA   |555555      |
+----------+-------+------------+
```

We can use a Window function to check the date of the previous row if we partition the data by `service` and `phone_number`, then sort by the date in ascending order:

```
df.withColumn(
    'prev_date', func.lag('date', 1).over(Window.partitionBy('service', 'phone_number').orderBy('date'))
).withColumn(
    'date_seq', func.sum(func.when(
        func.datediff(func.to_date(func.col('date'), 'dd/MM/yyyy'), func.to_date(func.col('prev_date'), 'dd/MM/yyyy'))<=3,
        func.lit(0)
    ).otherwise(
        func.lit(1)
    )).over(Window.partitionBy('service', 'phone_number').orderBy('date'))
).orderBy(
    ['service', 'phone_number', 'date']
).show(
    100, False
)+----------+-------+------------+----------+--------+
|date      |service|phone_number|prev_date |date_seq|
+----------+-------+------------+----------+--------+
|01/01/2023|AAAA   |555555      |null      |1       |
|02/01/2023|AAAA   |555555      |01/01/2023|1       |
|03/01/2023|AAAA   |555555      |02/01/2023|1       |
|10/01/2023|AAAA   |555555      |03/01/2023|2       |
+----------+-------+------------+----------+--------+
```

If the date difference is smaller than 3 days, then we don't need to assign a new `date_seq`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which rows are not in 3 days period, and add 1 for each rows cumulative.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['date', 'service', 'phone_number']) \
  .withColumn('date', f.to_timestamp('date', 'd/M/y'))

w = Window.partitionBy('service').orderBy('date')

df.withColumn('lag', f.lag('date').over(w)) \
  .withColumn('jump', f.coalesce(f.datediff('date', 'lag') > 3, f.lit(True))) \
  .withColumn('desired_seq', f.sum(f.col('jump').cast('int')).over(w)) \
  .drop('lag', 'jump') \
  .show()

+-------------------+-------+------------+-----------+
|               date|service|phone_number|desired_seq|
+-------------------+-------+------------+-----------+
|2021-11-10 00:00:00|   AAAA|      555555|          1|
|2022-05-23 00:00:00|   AAAA|      555555|          2|
|2021-12-09 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          1|
|2021-12-11 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          1|
|2022-01-14 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          2|
|2022-01-31 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          3|
|2022-02-14 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          4|
|2022-02-16 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          4|
|2022-03-24 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          5|
|2022-04-12 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          6|
|2022-04-13 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          6|
|2022-04-13 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          6|
|2022-05-04 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          7|
|2022-05-04 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          7|
|2022-05-21 00:00:00|   BBBB|      555555|          8|
+-------------------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: These approaches unfortunately does not work for me. :(
My goal is restart to counting from the last date of the 3-day rolling  interval. For example, if I have these dates in the group ('service', 'phone_number'): 06/06/2023, 06/06/2023,12/06/2023 I would like to get this: seq 1, 1, 2. At this point, since the window 1 is closed, the numbering of the second window will start from the date 12/06/2023 (seq=2). Then, after the date 12/06/2023 if I have the dates 17/06/2023, 18/06/2023 my output should be 2, 3, 3.